# React Native - Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined

Tags: ios, react-native

I was trying to build an app like the [react-native-starter-app](https://github.com/mcnamee/react-native-starter-app) .
All I did was installing packages mentioned in docs and modifying only the index.ios.js,

Error message:

[image]

Here's my code for index.ios.js:

```
'use strict';
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  NavigatorIOS,
  Component,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

var EventEmitter = require('EventEmitter');
var Subscribable = require('Subscribable');

 // 3rd Party Components
var NavigationBar = require('react-native-navbar');
var SideMenu = require('react-native-side-menu');

 // App Globals
var AppStyles = require('./ReactApp/styles.ios');

 // Components
var Icons = require('./ReactApp/components/icons.ios');
var Menu = require('./ReactApp/components/menu.ios');

 // Screens / Pages
var Index = require('./ReactApp/screens/tabbar.ios');

var NewsTable = require('./TFNewsTable');

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    }
});

class MyRNApp extends Component {

    render() {
        const menu = <Menu navigator={navigator}/>;

        return (
            <SideMenu menu={menu}>
                <NavigatorIOS
                style={styles.container}
                initialRoute={{
                    title: 'Title',
                    component: MyList,
                    leftButtonTitle: 'menu',
                }}/>
            </SideMenu>
        );
    }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyRNApp', () => MyRNApp);
```

The Subscribable.js file was in node_modules folder when I first initiated my app...
is this a bug or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to comment out those two lines with EventEmitter and Subscribable. Those libs should be used as mixins, so ES6 does not support it.